# Why getDrawable() doesn't work on some Android devices?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am getting "nosuchmethod error" on some user's phones (eg. Motorola Razr i) but it works fine on my HTC. Below is the code.

```
Drawable rBlack;
rBlack = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rblack, getTheme());
```

And the Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable
at org.petero.droidfish.myClass.onCreate(myClass.java:434)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And if I use this code:

```
flipButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.rblack));
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.myclass.getDrawable
at org.myclass.onCreate(myclass.java:435)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which part of that compound expression fails (hint, break it into multiple lines, then post the stack trace).  Where exactly is R.drawable.rblack defined?  Could it be in one dpi-specific folder but not in another?

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.myclass.getDrawable... rBlack is only inside the drawable folder, not inside the other hdpi, ldpi etc... Could this be the problem?

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat

Comment: That doesn't make any sense - `getDrawable()` should be a method of `Resources` not `org.myclass`

Comment: Show us the source of `myclass`

Comment: It is my main activity extends activity. I just had to edit the name when I put here because of company name was there.

Comment: @ChrisS sorry, I didn't understand what you mean by "source of myclass"

Comment: If it extends `android.app.Activity` try my answer but with `super.getDrawable(...)` instead of `getResources().getDrawable(...)` You shouldn't need to do that, but something is wonky with your class.

Comment: @savante - The other Chris is asking you to post the source of myclass.java and as something is seriously wrong with it, that is quite a necessary part of your question.

Comment: @ChrisS sorry guys, this error is from another part. it is like this: flipButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.rblack)); Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm going to bet it is failing on `getDrawable(R.drawable.rblack, getTheme());` which was added in API 21. Change that line to:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
    rBlack = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rblack, getTheme());
} else {
    rBlack = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rblack);
}
```

Comment: @savante : min SDK doesn't matter, only the SDK that you are on matters. Were you able to get it to work or not? Facing this same problem now.

Comment: @IcyFlame since savante accepted my answer after his/her comment I'd say it is safe to assume they got it working using my solution. If none of the solutions here work for you, I'd recommend asking a new question. You can even link to the solutions in this question as something you have already tried so you don't get flagged as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 29):

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context context, int id)
```

Comment: The question is *"Why getDrawable() doesn't work on some Android devices?"*. This doesn't answer the question at all. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11165112)

Comment: I bet he OP wanted a solution and not the technical reason of the crash. At the actual date, this the correct answer.

Comment: Same thing happened to me in some old device. It's safer to use ContextCompat's methods. Don't really know why getDrawable doesn't work, it should!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line of code:

```
context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image_name);
```