# Resources$NotFoundException on Android KitKat and lower

Tags: android, android-resources

I get app crash with Resources$NotFoundException emulating the app on version 4.4.4 and lower. On higher Android version everything works fine. This is the code:

```
image1.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(test_image,
                                "drawable", getResources().getString(R.string.app_package)));
```

Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Error log:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020090
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:204)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:327)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
                  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:69)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
```

Comment: You should debug and see what happens exactly. For example, does `getIdentifier` return a valid identifier or 0?

Comment: Have you tried using `R.drawable`?

Comment: post error log here

Comment: Please provide a complete code example with a class, a method, and all variable declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If XML:

Use `app:srcCompat` for ImageView and `app:drawableEndCompat` for Textview drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this: [Why getDrawable() doesn't work on some Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266971/why-getdrawable-doesnt-work-on-some-android-devices)

Try inserting before getResources "ContextCompat".
Like this:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context context, int id)
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue except I am not trying to get the resource at run time. However, I do have different values based on themes and the values are specified via ?attr/xyz and then xyz would be @drawable/pdq

The resources appear in the preview mode for API 19 but I get the not found exception at run time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0):

does drawable folders contain a drawable with `test_image` value ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I was using vector drawable for a textview drawableStart. Not sure why it was crashing with `Resources$NotFoundException` but I solved it by creating another vector drawable and wrapping the other one in a layer-list like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Note to future self: Need to wrap ic_nav_setting here. Was crashing on 4.4.1 without it-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_nav_setting"/>
</layer-list>
```

I hope this can help someone facing similar issue later

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody comes across this thread like me when searching for a solution for this problem:
Check if any of your resources are in version-dependent drawable folders, like src/main/res/drawable-v21. If so, move these to /main/res/drawable and rebuild your APK.